# Invoking API fails from web page, though succeeds in Test pages

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've create a API populated from a swagger.json file and verified it works in the Test UI.  The test UI request succeeds showing the headers passed below.

```
POST https://apiforqubo.azure-api.net/api/Qubo HTTP/1.1
Host: apiforqubo.azure-api.net
Content-Type: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
Ocp-Apim-Trace: true
```

I've added a CORS policy for all operations. This is now updated to reflect the answer below.

The updated policy is:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cors allow-credentials="true">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>https://apiforqubo.developer.azure-api.net</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>POST</method>
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>PUT</method>
            </allowed-methods>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

When I try to execute the API from the web page that's generated for the API at: https://apiforqubo.developer.azure-api.net/api-detail, the request fails with the error:

```
Unable to complete the request

Since the browser initiates the request, it requires Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) enabled on the server.
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE: policy statement to reflect specific website as suggested by Vitaliy Kurokhtin in the comments.

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've configured it to allow CORS requests only from `https://azure-api.net`, not from `https://apiforqubo.developer.azure-api.net`. Either use full URL or wildcard:

```
<origin>https://*.azure-api.net/</origin>
```

Comment: Good point.

After changing the origin https://apiforqubo.developer.azure-api.net and redeploying the website, unfortunately the error still occurs. Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly did you specify as origin? At what scope CORS policy is applied?

Comment: I'll update the original question with the new policy definition. However, as a snippet, for all policies, I updated:
```
<allowed-origins>
<origin>https://apiforqubo.developer.azure-api.net/</origin>
</allowed-origins>
```

Comment: See in browser dev console what is exactly being sent as OPTIONS request. I'm making OPTIONS call to https://apiforqubo.azure-api.net/api/Qubo, and I do get proper CORS response. So maybe Origin header that browser sends is different somehow. The main things to look for in OPTIONS request are Origin and Access-Control-Request-Method headers.

Comment: Found the issue, I needed to add allowed_headers and expose_headers xml stanzas as described in the doc:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal

Answer (score 0):

Please add allowed-headers policy element in your policy in APIM